# Check for multiple kv in a dictonary with a twist

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

I have a search list of dicts that I need to check if exist in another source dict.

```
source_dict = { 'a':'1', 'blue':'yes', 'c':'3' } 

search_list = [ {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}, {'blue': 'yes'} ]
```

The items in the list all need to be checked however, we need a AND for all items in the same dict. OR between dicts in the list.

How would I start to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` and `all`:

```
>>> # the `OR` (`any`) of the `AND`s (`all`s) for each dict
>>> any(all(k in source_dict and source_dict[k] == v for k, v in d.items()) for d in search_list)
True
>>> # the `AND`s (`all`s) for each dict
>>> [all(k in source_dict and source_dict[k] == v for k, v in d.items()) for d in search_list]
[False, True]
```

Comment: this did it for me.. nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
any(map(lambda x: all(map(lambda k: source_dict[k] == x[k] if k in source_dict else False, x.keys())), search_list))
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.